# Moving a WordPress site to a new server

Tags: admin, server, network-admin

I need to copy a WordPress site to a new server. I need this to go as quickly as possible. The URL won't change, but the absolute paths will.

Here are the steps I thought of:

- Put a maintenance message on the site
- Copy the database
- Copy all the files (the hidden ones as well, like .htaccess), with permissions
- Check if there are no old absolute paths, and if so, update them
- Check if everything's working
- Update the DNS records
- Remove the maintenance message

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Don't forget to update links in database too

Comment: @TweetPressFr thanks! Does that also apply when the URL doesn't change? I.e. are there absolute paths in the database?

Comment: It might be for some plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your steps are pretty much all you need to do, the only other thing I'd do is to use the [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin(I personally use it and it saves me a lot of time when migrating the Database) - it supports for change of both URL and paths - you can change one or both of them as well. So here's your list with my suggestion:

- Put a maintenance message on the site
- Install WP Migrate DB plugin on the WordPress site
- Copy the database, using the above plugin from **Tools > WP Migrate DB**
- Copy all the files (the hidden ones as well, like .htaccess), with permissions
- Check if there are no old absolute paths, and if so, update them(I'm not sure if you mean in files or what, but I assume there shouldn't be any in the files)
- Check if everything's working
- Update the DNS records
- Remove the maintenance message

In theory you can also use the [Maintenance Mode](http://wordpress.org/plugins/maintenance-mode/) for the maintenance message - I know it has the scary message that it hasn't been updated for over 2 years now, but honestly - I use it pretty much for every site I need to add temporary maintenance mode message and it works just great - I would usually add the 503.php file in the theme directory and make the plugin use that.

Comment: Great tool! That will save some time :)

Comment: Yeah - and the author released a pro version which has even more awesome features - I'm looking into saving some money and getting that, because it's really amazing :)

Answer (score -1):

You can change link by WORDPRESS SEARCH AND REPLACE TOOL wonderful tool, also WordPress recommend this tool, you can download by following url

http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: That's for changing domains. I'm not changing the domain, I'm changing the server only.